# Getting "Error removing file: Permission denied." in Arch when trying to delete a file with a right click

Tags: arch-linux

How can I avoid this problem? I am tired of having to delete everything by writing sudo every time. Is it possible to just grant root privileges to the user so I do not have to run sudo every single time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. You can log in as `root`, but that is dangerous and not recommended.

Instead, set the correct ownership on the files in the first place.

If they are your files, within for example, `/home/jsguy` then they should all (mostly?) be owned by you at which point you can delete them without using `sudo`.

However, if they are system files, for example, the list of users in `/etc/passwd` then allowing users to delete this would cause mayhem - nobody could log in.  Therefore, these files are owned by `root`, who is the only user who can delete them.  You temporarily become `root` using `sudo`.